# cordova android - code and version not updated

Tags: cordova, android-security

I've recently tried to update an application on Google Play store, and received a reject from Google because of some vulnerabilities inside cordova.

"The vulnerabilities were fixed in Apache Cordova v.4.1.1 or higher."

So, I tried to update cordova & cordova android :

`>cordova -v
6.4.0`

`>cordova platform ls
Installed platforms:
  android 6.0.0
  ios 3.8.0
  windows
Available platforms:
  amazon-fireos ~3.6.3 (deprecated)
  blackberry10 ~3.8.0
  browser ~4.1.0
  firefoxos ~3.6.3
  webos ~3.7.0
  windows ~4.4.0
  wp8 ~3.8.2 (deprecated)`

So, I think that everything is fine about my versions.

But, I really don't know why, now I have some problem about my code.

- When I try to upload the new version, google say that I did not change the version number (which is false, I've change it)
- When I look at my app on a tablet, all bug corrections I've done are not here (it's an old version, don't know why), but if I look at my application on a desktop, all bug corrections are here.

I think that both problem are linked, but I really don't know why.
I've past the result of "cordova run android" cmd, and I see a "skipping build".

Does anyone have an idea about the problem? Thanks a lot

`>cordova run android
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:prepareDebugDependencies
:CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl
:CordovaLib:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileLint
:CordovaLib:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugShaders
:CordovaLib:compileDebugShaders
:CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResources
:CordovaLib:packageDebugResources
:CordovaLib:processDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig
:CordovaLib:processDebugResources
:CordovaLib:generateDebugSources
:CordovaLib:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard
:CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
:CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
:CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug
:CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForDebug
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugJniLibFolders
:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug
:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForDebug
:CordovaLib:bundleDebug
:prepareAndroidCordovaLibUnspecifiedDebugLibrary
:prepareDebugDependencies
:compileDebugAidl
:compileDebugRenderscript
:generateDebugBuildConfig
:generateDebugResValues
:generateDebugResources
:mergeDebugResources
:processDebugManifest
:processDebugResources
:generateDebugSources
:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard
:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugSources
:mergeDebugShaders
:compileDebugShaders
:generateDebugAssets
:mergeDebugAssets
:transformClassesWithDexForDebug
:mergeDebugJniLibFolders
:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug
:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug
:validateSigningDebug
:packageDebug
:assembleDebug
:cdvBuildDebug`

`BUILD SUCCESSFUL`

`Total time: 5.293 secs
Built the following apk(s):
        D:/dev/app/appName/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65
No target specified, deploying to device 'R32D203NC4M'.
Skipping build...
Built the following apk(s):
        D:/dev/app/appName/platforms/android/ant-build/MainActivity-debug.apk
        D:/dev/app/appName/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk
Using apk: D:/dev/app/appName/platforms/android/ant-build/MainActivity-debug.apk
Package name: yyy.app1_0
LAUNCH SUCCESS`

Is it normal to have two builds? "MainActivity.apk" & "android-debug.apk"?

Edit: It seems thats the "MainActivity.apk" which is used is not the last version if I compate "modification date" on windows

Comment: first remove app from device and try may be cache issue, then issue still presist please remove and add platform and try

Comment: it seems that after remove/add, only one apk is build, but all XHR request are not 404 (from cache)
Seems that I'm not the only one with the cache problem, i need to check cordova whitelist plugin

Comment: if you have upgraded cordova 2 .apk files will generate at **platforms\android\build\outputs\apk** 1) **android-debug.apk** and 2) **android-debug-unaligned.apk** and you need to use 1st one

Comment: Yup, it was just a problem with cordova whitlist. Just add it, and it seems to work. Just have to find minor bugs (icon missing, etc ...) and try upload it to the store !

Comment: Does the change version or remove/add can have any effect about icon ?

`<platform name="android">
  <icon src="res/mipmap-ldpi/icon.png" density="ldpi" />
  <icon src="res/mipmap-mdpi/icon.png" density="mdpi" />
  <icon src="res/mipmap-hdpi/icon.png" density="hdpi" />
  <icon src="res/mipmap-xhdpi/icon.png" density="xhdpi" />
 </platform>`

But icon, is now the cordova default

Comment: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/images.html for more details

Comment: i think you need to change size and mentioned icons in config.xml like give in above link

Comment: Yup, that's what i'm currently reading but everything seems fine, but nvm, thanks a lot :)

Comment: more informations about missing icon :
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-12077